# Passing undefined function parameters to another function (as undefined) without triggering an error?

Tags: javascript

Google Analytics' legacy `ga.js` tracking uses a method which sometimes requires function arguments to be passed as `undefined`:

> `_trackEvent(category, action, opt_label, opt_value, opt_noninteraction)` 
> You can use any of the following optional parameters: opt_label, opt_value or opt_noninteraction. If you want to provide a value only for the second or 3rd optional parameter, you need to pass in undefined for the preceding optional parameter.

I want to create a wrapper function which takes the same parameters but is capable of passing any missing optional ones to the GA function as `undefined`.

Here's what I've got:

```
function track(category, action, opt_label, opt_value, opt_noninteraction) {
    if (navigator.doNotTrack != "1") {
        _gaq.push(["_trackEvent", category, action, opt_label, opt_value, opt_noninteraction]);
    }
}
```

When I use the function like `track("Test", "Click", , 1)`, however, it throws a syntax error, saying `opt_label is undefined`.

I kind of expected that to happen, but how do I fix it? How do I ensure any empty optional arguments are passed as `undefined` as Google requires without triggering the error?

Comment: `ReferenceError` is usually when the variable doesn't exist. I don't think your example throws that error?

Comment: You can't leave out arguments in the middle of the argument list. You have to write `track("Test", "Click", undefined, 1)`

Comment: You can only omit arguments at the end, they'll default to `undefined`.

Comment: @Barmar I'm confused. The example given won't throw a reference error, even if no arguments are passed in

Comment: @evolutionxbox That's true. I upvoted your comment. His code should get a syntax error.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Sorry, my fault. It's a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

You can receive the parameters in shape of an object in your wrapper function:

```
function track({ category, action, opt_label, opt_value, opt_noninteraction }) {
    if (navigator.doNotTrack != "1") {
        _gaq.push(["_trackEvent", category, action, opt_label, opt_value, opt_noninteraction]);
    }
}
```

Now you can call track function with optional params as well:
`track({ opt_value: 1 })`, all of the params will be undefined, except opt_value.

Otherwise its not possible in javascript, the feature you're looking for is called labelled parameters in ReasonML, which you can look over [here](http://reasonmlhub.com/exploring-reasonml/ch_functions.html#labeled-parameters).